# Selecting Specific JSON Response Items in python 3

Tags: json, python-3.x

I'm new to coding in python. I generally use html but I thought it was time to dive into something new. After hours of searching and reading here, I'm still puzzled.

I'm trying to select specific data from this JSON response. e.g a team name or event id. How to do so?

This is what the python code and JSON response looks.

```
import http.client
import json
from pprint import pprint

torneo = "424"
connection = http.client.HTTPConnection('api.football-data.org')
headers = { 'X-Auth-Token': '64172e9f948849e59f8b48ec17a3480d', 'X-Response-Control': 'minified' }
connection.request('GET', '/v1/soccerseasons/%s/fixtures/?timeFrame=n1' % torneo, None, headers )
response = json.loads(connection.getresponse().read().decode())
pprint (response)



    {'count': 4,
 'fixtures': [{'awayTeamId': 794,
               'awayTeamName': 'Poland',
               'date': '2016-06-21T16:00:00Z',
               'homeTeamId': 790,
               'homeTeamName': 'Ukraine',
               'id': 149863,
               'matchday': 3,
               'result': {'goalsAwayTeam': None, 'goalsHomeTeam': None},
               'soccerseasonId': 424,
               'status': 'TIMED'},
              {'awayTeamId': 759,
               'awayTeamName': 'Germany',
               'date': '2016-06-21T16:00:00Z',
               'homeTeamId': 829,
               'homeTeamName': 'Northern Ireland',
               'id': 149862,
               'matchday': 3,
               'result': {'goalsAwayTeam': None, 'goalsHomeTeam': None},
               'soccerseasonId': 424,
               'status': 'TIMED'},
              {'awayTeamId': 803,
               'awayTeamName': 'Turkey',
               'date': '2016-06-21T19:00:00Z',
               'homeTeamId': 798,
               'homeTeamName': 'Czech Republic',
               'id': 149869,
               'matchday': 3,
               'result': {'goalsAwayTeam': None, 'goalsHomeTeam': None},
               'soccerseasonId': 424,
               'status': 'TIMED'},
              {'awayTeamId': 760,
               'awayTeamName': 'Spain',
               'date': '2016-06-21T19:00:00Z',
               'homeTeamId': 799,
               'homeTeamName': 'Croatia',
               'id': 149868,
               'matchday': 3,
               'result': {'goalsAwayTeam': None, 'goalsHomeTeam': None},
               'soccerseasonId': 424,
               'status': 'TIMED'}]}
Press ENTER to exit
```

Answer (score 1):

I seem to have solved it if anyone would find it useful.

```
for each in (response['fixtures']):
    pprint (each['id'])
```

This gives me exactly what I wanted.